# If $F$ has characteristic $p$ and $f(x)=x^p-a\in F[x]$, then $f(x)$ is either irreducible over $F$ or $f(x)$ splits in $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $F$ has characteristic $p$ and $a\in F$,consider
    the polynomial $f(x)=x^p-a\in F[x]$. Prove that $f(x)$ is either
    irreducible over $F$ or $f(x)$ splits in $F$.

I am thinking that if $f$ reduces but not to linear functions then I can find a contradiction. I don't see how the characteristic becomes important though.

Comment: If $char F = 0$ then $f$ may have multiple roots.

Comment: So perhaps it is has only multiple roots or no roots at all. I just read up on characteristic and discovered the freshman's dream. This seems promising.

Comment: $f$ have no multiple roots since $f' = -1$ and coprome with $f$

Comment: in a field of characteristic $p$, what is $(x-b)^p$?

Comment: I think it's x^p - b^p.

Comment: If $f(x)=(x-a)^p$ how can it be f irreducible?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, don't see that $f = x^p-a$(i see that $a=1$)

Comment: So using the freshman's dream we can rewrite f so that it is already split, assuming it has a zero.  But can't it reduce without a zero?

Comment: @OLP No, it can’t.  I gave a hint in my answer.  See if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be a splitting field for $f$ and $α ∈ L$ be a root of $f$.  Then $α^p = a$, so you can write $f$ as $f = X^p - α^p$.

Do you know the [Frobenius endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism)?  Factor $f$ in $L[X]$ and look at its possible divisors.  What happens if any of its proper divisors is in $F[X]$?  Expand it and look at its second-highest coefficient.

---

Since $f = X^p - α^p = (X - α)^p$, all proper divisors of $f$ are $(X-α), …, (X-α)^{p-1}$. But for any $n ∈ ℕ_0$,

$$(X-α)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}X^k·(-α)^{n-k} = X^n \pm nαX^{n-1} + \text{lower degree stuff}.$$

So if any proper divisor $(X-α)^n$ for some $n ∈ 1,…,p-1$ is in $F[X]$, then all its coefficients, including the second highest, are in $F$.  So $nα ∈ F$, but if $n ∈ 1,…,p-1$, then $n$ is invertible in $F$ and $α ∈ F$.

Thus, if $f$ is reducible in $F[X]$, it contains some proper divisor, but then it also contains its root $α$ and already splits as $f = (X-α)^p$ in $F[X]$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to process this. Is the endomorphism necessary? We haven't discussed it. Could you explain the game plan here? I can't see the big picture.

Comment: Is that any of its proper divisors are themselves already split?

Comment: @OLP  Don’t worry too much about the word »Frobenius homomorphism«, you already realized that the Freshman’s Dream holds and $f$ splits as $f = (X-α)^p$ (in its splitting field).  I’ve added another hint.  How do proper divisors of $f$ look like in $L$?

Comment: »Frobenius endomorphism« is just a fancy name for any map given by $x ↦ x^q$ whenever the Freshman’s Dream $(x+y)^q = x^q + y^q$ holds (so whenever the given map is additive/an endomorphism of an abelian group).  Don’t worry about it, but keep it in mind because it’s very important.

Comment: So it seems that all the proper divisors are already split in L. I feel that the issue is whether the root is also in F or not. The second highest coefficient is divisible by the root found in E. Sorry, I still can't put the pieces together.

Comment: @OLP Yeah, I’ve updated it.

Comment: So the homomorphism is used to associate proper divisors over L with proper divisors over F? Since the pullback is 1-1 for images of polynomials with coefficients in F? Thanks for the help. This seems like a great approach.

Comment: Also multiplication by n is just iterated addition, right? Since n is not an element of the field?

Comment: Actually  we can write na = a + a+ a +... = a(1+ 1 + ...) where the sum of the units is an element of F since n is less than p.

Comment: The Frobenius homomorphism is used in (or rather mentioned to justify) the step $X^p-α^p = (X-α)^p$. Divisors of polynomials don’t change by expanding the field of coefficients – if $g ∈ F[X]$ is monic and  $g | f$ in $F[X]$, then trivially $g | f$ in $L[X]$, hence $g = (X-α)^n$ in $L[X]$ for some $n ∈ ℕ_0$. Then you can expand $g$ in $L$ and conclude like I’ve done it.